# How to run Nest+React app with docker-compose if both containers work fine separately

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nestjs

I try to run both React and Nest apps with `docker-compose up`, but it fails while running the server.
However, there is not problems when starting 2 containers separately.

The error is:

```
server  | Unknown command: "start:dev"
server  | 
server  | Did you mean one of these?
server  |     npm run start:dev # run the "start:dev" package script
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
    client:
        container_name: client
        build:
            context: ./client
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: client
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        volumes:
            - ./client:/app
    server:
        container_name: server
        build:
            context: ./server
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: server
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
            - ./server:/app
```

Server Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR ./app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

ENV PORT=8080

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

Client Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR ./app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The issue is with `docker-compose.yml`, but I can't see if it's connected to nest or docker.
Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: That seems like it should work to me.  There are several unnecessary options in your Compose file, which could potentially result in issues; does deleting the `image:`, `container_name:`, and especially `volumes:` blocks help things at all?

Comment: @DavidMaze Not sure, but i'll try it asap, thank you for the hint!

Comment: That actually helped me! 
How is that possible? I thought `container_name` and `image` are just meta infos.
Can it be that `volume` somehow mistreats the directories?

Comment: The `volumes:` setup overwrites everything the Dockerfile does, so if the host's filesystem layout or contents don't match what's in the image perfectly, you can get errors like this.  (Hiding the installed `node_modules` tree is probably a little more likely.)  The `image:` and `container_name:` don't seem to conflict, but without them Compose will pick something unique on its own.

Comment: @DavidMaze I see, thank you a lot for the help. Will need to go through the docs to understand the yml structure better.